# VueJS: How to render several elements per cycle?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I need to render the next list:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="type-1-0">some content</li>
  <li class="type-1-1">some content</li>
  ...
  <li class="type-99-0">some content</li>
  <li class="type-99-1">some content</li>   
</ul>
```

Can I use the "v-for" directive for this?

Comment: yes, if you have something, on what you can iterate....

Answer (score 1):

Use a [range v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range) in combination with a `template` tag.

```
<ul id="list">
  <template v-for="n of 99">
    <li :class="`type-${n}-0`">some content</li>
    <li :class="`type-${n}-1`">some content</li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul id="list">
    <template v-for="n of 99">
      <li :class="`type-${n}-0`">{{`type-${n}-0`}}</li>
      <li :class="`type-${n}-1`">{{`type-${n}-1`}}</li>
    </template>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note: if you need to support IE, you will either need to use the `template` tag in a string template (or single file component) or use a render function instead.  because `template` is not supported in IE.